# Is it a good practice to write code like List<String[]> in java?

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to write code like `List<String[]>` in java? Would there be a problem?

If not. Which way is better: `List<List<String>>` or `List<String[]>` . And why?

---

Edit:

the question may seems stupid. Today one of my colleague asks me this question, and I realized that I seldom see code like `List<String[]>` in great java projects. I just want to know why.

Comment: It depends on you intentions.  `List<String[]>` might suggest that the contents is not-mutable or is a fixed number of values (obviously), where as `List<List<String>>` might suggest that the contents is mutable. Unfortunately Java does not have a concept of non-mutable list, which would provide context and allow callers to known when they can/should update the underlying data

Comment: In my opinion, I would use `Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList)` to create an non-mutable list. And I think it is better than `String[]` in case of mutable, since elements in a `String[]` variable may still be changed, while `Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList)` may not.

Comment: The problem is `List` has mutable modifiers (`add`, `remove`, etc...), so, it's impossible to know by just reading the code what the intention is

Comment: *"Which way is better: `List<List<String>>` or `List<String[]>`?"* Neither. Both. You use the one you need. --- *To illustrate:* Which is better: `List<Apple>` or `List<Orange>`? If you have apples the first is best, if you have oranges the second the best. --- You're asking apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your requirement.

If you want to make a list of String array where number of string present in each array is fixed and you know the number beforehand, then you can go with `List <String[]>`

But if you doesn't have any idea regarding the number of string present in each list inside the list beforehand and the number of string will be decided in run time, you have to go with `List<List<String>>`

Thinks it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a problem if you write `List<String[]>` and use it correctly.

Let me explain their differences:

`List<String[]>` is a List of an array of String

`List<List<String>>` is a List of a List of String

I prefer `List<List<String>>` over the other since it's easier to work with `List<String>` than `String[]`. After all, `List` was created to solve the usability problems with arrays. `List` allows you to easily get, put, delete, and do all sort of other operations possible with an array, thanks to its ready-to-use functions (check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).